# How to get the category (Label) of a post from RSS with SimplePie

Tags: rss, simplepie

Is there any member function available in SimplePie to get the Category (Labels) of a post ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the get_categories() function...

```
foreach ($item->get_categories() as $category)
    {
        echo $category->get_label();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to superUntitled's answer

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://simplepie.org/blog/feed/');
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item)
{
    if ($category= $item->get_category())
    {
        echo $category->get_label();

    }
}
```

NB: it is also the same for term and scheme:

```
echo $category->get_term();
echo $category->get_scheme();
```

from simplepie documentation:

- http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_category/start
- http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_category/get_label
- http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_category/get_term
- http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_category/get_scheme